# android studio where does the calendar get the time from

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have an old android phone with no SIM card that I want to use to test smaller screens with my timecard app, what I'm wondering is, where does the calendar method,

For example:

```
   Calender now = Calendar.getInstance()
```

get the time from? A server or does it get the time data directly from the android cellphone?

Comment: From the cellphone, which (usually) gets it from the cellular network. It's possible to disable that in the preferences.

Comment: you see those numbers in the top right corner of the screen? That's the time your phone think it is.

Comment: Thats fine sir, but i asked where does the calender code get that info from, the phone itself or does it connect and find it from a time server, I realize for people who know the answer to that question that it is a simple question, which obviously i did not know and is why i asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method getInstance returns a calendar whose locale is based on system settings and whose time fields have been initialized with the current date and time.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Thanks very much, and i just checked that link and it had good info on special circumstances which might apply to having no external time access